# Adding ICal on email not supporting HTML body along with it in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, icalendar

I have a problem with ICAL in email.Every thing is working except the html body. if i don't have the ical then html body showing in email but if i use the ICAL the full html is showing as text.
Can anyone tell me what is the problem with this code!

```
public static void SendHTMLEmailWithGoogleInvite(string from, string to, string subj, string body, DateTime date)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    try { mm.To.Add(to); }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid receiver email address please update and retry again.", ex);

    }
    mm.To.Add(to);
    from.Split();
    mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
    mm.Subject = subj;
    mm.Body = body;
    mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SMTPServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailServer"]);
    SMTPServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
    SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pwd"]);

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//GeO");
    str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
    str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
    str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", date));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", date));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", date));
    str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + "KOLKATA");
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));

    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", mm.Body));

    str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", mm.Body));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", mm.Subject));


    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", mm.From.Address));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:{1}", mm.From.DisplayName, mm.From.Address));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;SCHEDULE-STATUS=1.2:mailto:{1}", mm.To[0].DisplayName, mm.To[0].Address));



    str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
    str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT24H");
    str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
    str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Reminder");
    str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
    str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
    str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
    System.Net.Mime.ContentType type = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
    type.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
    //type.Parameters.Add("method", "PUBLISH");
    type.Parameters.Add("name", "ginvite.ics");
    mm.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), type));

    SMTPServer.Send(mm);

}
```

Attached the screenshot of the email where the html body is showing as html text with all tags.

[image: This HTML mail body is showing as text in the email which is the problem]

Comment: When code works the body is an html section of the email. You can add multiple views.  See : http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/3.1.3.aspx

Comment: @jdweng This line is not supported for html content ?

str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", mm.Body));
str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", mm.Body));

Comment: Why are you using string.Format?  It says on link you can have an alternate body (I guess instead of Alternate View).

Comment: @jdweng i tried adding alternate views but still same issue. i dont know if i am doing wrong.

Comment: You need to create a mail message (see my link) and then add object to the message.  Not create strings.

Comment: @jdweng That is a mail message.and that string part is code to generate Ical which i am adding as alternateView.

Comment: Each string  builder should be a different view.  You are putting two views into one string builder.  Look at example : lternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("This is my plain text content, viewable by those clients that don't support html", null, "text/plain");  It has three parameters 1) the string 2) null 3) "text/plain"  You cannot put the three parameters into one string.

Comment: @jdweng i tried different views also after you told but still i see same issue. having the ical invite in mail the html view is not supported . only text is showing.

i did add 2nd view for the html body along with this view for ical invite.

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the help . Well i am able to make it work. I had to add the mime type
text/html for the html view then it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Finally ! i am able to make it work. I had to add the html content with seperate view with mime type text/html

```
    public static void SendHTMLEmailWithGoogleInvite(string from, string to, string subj, string body, DateTime date)
{
    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage mm = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    try { mm.To.Add(to); }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception("Invalid receiver email address please update and retry again.", ex);

    }
    mm.To.Add(to);
    from.Split();
    mm.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(from);
    mm.Subject = subj; 
    System.Net.Mime.ContentType typeHtml = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");

    AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, typeHtml);
    mm.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);


    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient SMTPServer = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailServer"]);
    SMTPServer.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
    SMTPServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SMTPUser"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Pwd"]);

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
    str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//GeO");
    str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
    str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
    str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", date));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", date));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", date));
    str.AppendLine("LOCATION: " + "KOLKATA");
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid())); 
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", body));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", body));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:{0}", mm.Subject));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", mm.From.Address));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED:mailto:{1}", mm.From.DisplayName, mm.From.Address));
    str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;SCHEDULE-STATUS=1.2:mailto:{1}", mm.To[0].DisplayName, mm.To[0].Address)); 
    str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
    str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT24H");
    str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
    str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION;ENCODING=QUOTED-PRINTABLE:Reminder");
    str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
    str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
    str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");
    System.Net.Mime.ContentType type = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
    type.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST"); 
    type.Parameters.Add("name", "ginvite.ics");
    mm.AlternateViews.Add(AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), type)); 
    SMTPServer.Send(mm);

}
```